# Head usage unknown option -1 / -n error. Possibly ruby related

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I have a recurring problem when starting the terminal in OSX 10.9.1.

Every time I start the terminal I get the following repeated at least 30 times

```
Unknown option: 1
Usage: head [-options] <url>...
-m <method>   use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')
-f            make request even if head believes method is illegal
-b <base>     Use the specified URL as base
-t <timeout>  Set timeout value
-i <time>     Set the If-Modified-Since header on the request
-c <conttype> use this content-type for POST, PUT, CHECKIN
-a            Use text mode for content I/O
-p <proxyurl> use this as a proxy
-P            don't load proxy settings from environment
-H <header>   send this HTTP header (you can specify several)

-u            Display method and URL before any response
-U            Display request headers (implies -u)
-s            Display response status code
-S            Display response status chain
-e            Display response headers
-d            Do not display content
-o <format>   Process HTML content in various ways

-v            Show program version
-h            Print this message

-x            Extra debugging output
```

followed finally by

```
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 63: rbenv---version: command not found
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 63: rbenv-help: command not found
```

and this repeated 50ish times

```
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 63: rbenv---version: command not found
/usr/local/bin/rbenv: line 63: rbenv-help: command not found
```

Figuring it's Ruby related, I tried

```
rvm get stable
```

and

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

but then get the error:

> SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I've also tried repairing permissions (as usual) with no solution (as usual)

This isn't an area I'm familiar with so I not sure which tree to bark up now. 
Can anyone help?

Here are the .bashrc and .bash_profile contents as requested

.bashrc contents:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

.bash_profile contents:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/stevekirkby/.rvm/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/stevekirkby/.rvm/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

alias htdocs='cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs'
alias home='cd /Users/stevekirkby'
```

Thanks, Steve

Comment: You've installed something that wanted to be called `/usr/bin/HEAD` on the OS X case-insensitive filesystem. I know there's an awful Perl HTTP package that does this, but you could have installed something else that does it too.

Comment: I hope everyone who reads this question takes this as a strong argument in favor of *not* printing a usage statement in response to an invocation error.  "Unknown option: 1" is all that is needed; the rest is noise.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: to be fair, that usage statement made it much easier to tell that an HTTP HEAD tool was running instead of the normal head(1) program...

Comment: Thanks wooble. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you show your .bashrc and .bash_profile files?

Comment: Hi Ismael, added to the original post. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the os x file `/usr/bin/head`?  As I understand @Wobble's point, you probably installed an app that replaced your file `head` with a file named `HEAD`.  The developer presumably assumed `head` and `HEAD` would be distinct files, as is the case on non-Mac unix's.  I don't know if you can just replace HEAD with os x's head, though that would undoubtedly break the app that's causing the problem.  Whoops.  Just noticed you solved the problem.  Did you ever find out why you had the file `/usr/bin/HEAD`?

Comment: Hi Cary, thanks for the response. The head file was lowercase so I figured that wasn't the problem. Looks like it was rvm-related and most likely, caused by me fouling up the permissions somewhere. Removing rvm as described and reinstalling solved it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. It stems from `rbenv` trying to use `head -1` in one of it's scripts, but failing.

The problem is that your (and my for that matter) `.bash_profile` contains:

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
```

And the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` folder contains a script named `HEAD` (named after the HTTP method) and a case-insensitive file system in conjunction with bash (as ZSH did not have this problem) gets `head` and `HEAD` mixed up and serves whichever comes first in `$PATH`b.

As a solution:

- either remove `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` from your `$PATH` (or move it last)
- Or, as I did, `mv HEAD HTTP_HEAD` in that folder.

PS. the latter option might break some XAMPP scripts but I still need correct XAMPP php version in my path.

Comment: Leaving `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin"` worked for me, thanks

Comment: Removing `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` from $PATH fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using

```
rvm implode
```

to remove the ruby version manager

Then followed the instructions at the end of the uninstaller removing references to rvm in the .bashrc, .bash_profile and .zshrc in my username folder.